# Delete words with capital letters

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to delete all words that start with capital letters but below is just catching "Al" from the first word:

```
echo "Always baby Yeah" | sed -r 's/^([AEIOU].)//g'
```

How do I capture just all the words starting with capital letters?

Answer (score 2):

You only remove the first two characters and only if they are at the start of the string.

Use: `sed -r 's/\b[A-Z]\w*//g'` or `'s/\b[A-Z]\w*\s*//g'` if you want to remove the whitespace too.

Answer (score 0):

below regex should be helpful for you

```
m/(^[A-Z]\w*)/
```

Comment: no, that will remove *everthing* after (starting from) the capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work `\b[A-Z](\w*)\b`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "Always baby Yeah" | sed -r 's/\b[A-Z](\w*)\b//g'
 baby
```