# Delete words with capital letters in bash

Tags: bash, sed, tr

How do you delete words in a string in BASH that have capital letters?
Ex.

Input:

```
Taco burrito Mexico fiesta
```

Output:

```
burrito fiesta
```

The solution I saw on Stack Overflow doesn't work for me since the linux machine I'm working with doesn't accept the `-r` switch.

Comment: Which `sed` do you have?

Comment: Can you link to the solution you saw here?

Comment: Is the capital letter always the first letter of the word?

Comment: The solution from @anubhava seemed to do the trick!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424469/delete-words-with-capital-letters?rq=1

Comment: In my case, yes, the words in my file only start with capital letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
s='Taco burrito Mexico fiesta'
sed 's/[[:upper:]][^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*//g' <<< "$s"
```

```
burrito fiesta
```

**Details:**

- `[[:upper:]]`: Matches an uppercase letter
- `[^[:blank:]]`: Matches any character except a space or tab character
- `[[:blank:]]`: Matches a space or tab character

Comment: What if the capital letter is not leading the word? Although OP’s examples only have this, the question does not limit the capital to only being the first char of a word. In fact your solution would turn `fooBar` into `foo`, which deletes *part* of a word.

Comment: @Bohemian I would happily taken care of if that was OP's requirement. Word boundaries in sed are not platform agnostic. Will check this thread in my morning, good night.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, perl

```
perl -aE 'say "@{[ grep {not /^[[:upper:]]/} @F ]}"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo Taco burrito Mexico fiesta | awk '{gsub(/ (\S*[A-Z]\S*)|(\S*[A-Z]\S* )/, "")}1'
burrito fiesta
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash`:

```
set -- Taco burrito Mexico fiesta ; LC_ALL=C; echo ${@/*[A-Z]*}
```

Or:

```
a=(Taco burrito Mexico fiesta) ; LC_ALL=C; echo ${a[@]/*[A-Z]*}
```

Output (of either):

```
burrito fiesta
```